# Design matrix rank does not match

Tags: matrix, fitting

I'm attempting to fit a linear model and Mathematica returns the error message: "The rank of the design matrix 9 is less than the number of terms 10 in the model. The model and results based upon it may contain significant numerical error."

Basically I imported a .csv file w/ my data. 10 columns, 6199 rows. My dependent variable is in the last column of the .csv. Is my LinearModelFit the proper syntax?

```
dat = Import["/Users/Desktop/Final/data.csv"];

Dimensions[dat]


(* {6199, 10} *)

dat1 = Transpose[dat]

Dimensions[dat1]


(* {10, 6199} *)

reg = LinearModelFit[dat, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}]
```

> During evaluation of In[220]:= LinearModelFit::rank: The rank of the design matrix 9 is less than  the number of terms 10 in the model. The model and results based upon it may contain  significant numerical error. >>

Comment: It means the 9x6199 submatrix of data positions does not have full rank. Contrast behavior of `LinearModelFit[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 3}}, {x, y}, {x, y}]` with `LinearModelFit[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}, {x, y}, {x, y}]`. The submatrices in question are `{{0,0},{0,1},{0,2}}` which is rank deficient, and `{{0,0},{0,1},{`,2}}` which has full rank of 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I pulled the data into Stata to look for any missing or non-zero/one values in the binary variables. I couldn't find anything so I assumed it must be the file format. I'm not sure if that was the case but I got it working with:    DesignMatrix[home, {x1, x2}, {x1, x2}] // MatrixForm

Answer (score 6):

A matrix ${\bf A}$ and its rank may be thought of as follows. Given a linear function $f({\bf X}) = {\bf A}.{\bf X}$, where ${\bf A}$ gives the coefficients of the variables ${\bf X} = (x_1,\dots,x_m)$, the **rank** is the maximum number of independent equations of the system $f({\bf X}) = {\bf 0}$ that can be found.  The **null space** of the matrix ${\bf A}$ consists of all vectors ${\bf dX}$ that make zero difference in the output, i.e., $f({\bf X}+{\bf dX})=f({\bf X})$.    If the rank is equal the number of variables (which equals the number of columns), the null space will consist of just the zero vector, and there will be a unique solution to the system $f({\bf X}) = {\bf 0}$.

[`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearModelFit.html) uses the data to set up a linear function of the $n+1$ parameters of the $n$ basis functions for the model plus the constant basis function $1$.  The array of coefficients of the parameters, which are equal to the values of the basis functions on the data points, is called the **design matrix**.  The data also defines a **response vector** ${\bf Y}$. Then `LinearModelFit` finds an ${\bf X}$ that minimizes the sum of squares of the differences in the vector $f({\bf X}) - {\bf Y}$.  If the rank of the design matrix is less than the number of variables, then the null space contains nonzero vectors ${\bf dX}$, so that $f({\bf X})$ and $f({\bf X}+{\bf dX})$ both minimize the error.  There will be infinitely many solutions, which means infinitely many models, but that should be okay because a deficient rank also implies that there are linear relationships between the parameters.  The relationships imply that the models are equivalent.

Further the warning message implies that there may **numerical** error.  I suppose this is probably from using approximate, machine numbers.  It seems likely that some quantities that should be zero, will only be close to zero.  These might lead to significant computational errors.

**OP's problem**

Some random data, except that it makes the first two parameters `b0` and `b1`, the ones for the functions `1` and `x1`, satisfy the relation `b0 + b1 == constant`.

```
SeedRandom[0];
dat = Prepend[RandomReal[1, {9, 6199}], ConstantArray[1., 6199]] // Transpose;
reg = LinearModelFit[
   dat, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9}];
```

> LinearModelFit::rank: The rank of the design matrix 9 is less than the number of terms 10 in the model. The model and results based upon it may contain significant numerical error. >>

In the OP's case, the rank is deficient by 1, which means the null space is the set of all scalar multiples of a single vector. [`NullSpace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NullSpace.html) returns a list of vectors that form a basis for the null space.  Each vector represents an independent change in the values of the parameters that produces another solution.  `NullSpace` computes its answer with a certain numerical [`Tolerance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Tolerance.html), and quantities that should cancel sometimes might not come out to zero.  We can use `Chop` to make small numbers and small differences equal zero.

```
ns = NullSpace[reg["DesignMatrix"]]
Chop[%]
(*
  {{-0.707107, 0.707107, -7.21645*10^-16, 1.15186*10^-15, 
     2.498*10^-16, -2.69229*10^-15, 2.67841*10^-15, 5.68989*10^-16, 
     5.55112*10^-16, 4.02456*10^-16}}

  {{-0.707107, 0.707107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
*)
```

This means we can change the parameters by `a*{-0.707107, 0.707107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`, for any scalar `a` to get another solution and model.  In general, we can change the parameters by

```
{a1, a2,..., ak}.ns
```

for any `k` scalars `a1`, `a2`,... where `k` is the number of vectors in the basis `ns` for the null space. This can be verified for our random example as follows.  A set of parameters is a solution if it satisfies

```
reg["DesignMatrix"].parameters == reg["PredictedResponse"]
```

For instance, the solution `reg["BestFitParameters"]` satisfies

```
reg["DesignMatrix"].reg["BestFitParameters"] == reg["PredictedResponse"]
(*  True  *)
```

We can check that an arbitrary change `{a}.NullSpace[reg["DesignMatrix"]]` by an element of the null space yields another solution:

```
reg["DesignMatrix"].
 (reg["BestFitParameters"] + {a}.NullSpace[reg["DesignMatrix"]]) == 
   reg["PredictedResponse"] // Simplify // Chop
(*  True  *)
```

This problem arises when one of the basis functions is a linear combination of the others.  For instance, if the functions include the numbers of males, females, and persons (both genders), then there is the linear relationship, persons = males + females, and the rank of the design matrix will be deficient.

Comment: Very nice explanation indeed !